# Align and oversetting an equal sign

Tags: equations, align

this is my first questoin on tex.stack. I hope, that my SRE is short and precise enough to help me. Basically I want to align all equations unter the "=". In the align environment wen handle this by using "&". However, it doesnt work if I want to overset the "=":

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y     

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
0 &=\partial \Big(\frac{1}{2N} ||\y- \X\beta||_{2}^2\Big) \\
&\overset{\mathrm{Def. 1}}{=} \nabla \Big(\frac{1}{2N} ||\y- \X\beta||_{2}^2\Big) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I also tried to set the & inside

```
\overset{\mathrm{Def. 1}}{&=} \nabla \Big(\frac{1}{2N} ||\y- \X\beta||_{2}^2\Big)
```

But I get an error

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which error do you get and what does not work (the alignment)?

Comment: ! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.24 \end{align*}
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty version to use the same width for both which results in correct alignment. I do not recommend this method if you use this regularly (although it might yield the desired result if your "Def X." is always of the same width, e.g. with table numbers).

[image: settowidth alignment]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y     

\newlength{\tempdef}
\settowidth{\tempdef}{\({}\overset{\mathrm{Def. 1}}{=}{}\)}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
0 &\makebox[\tempdef][c]{=}\partial \Big(\frac{1}{2N} ||\y- \X\beta||_{2}^2\Big) \\
&\overset{\mathrm{Def. 1}}{=} \nabla \Big(\frac{1}{2N} ||\y- \X\beta||_{2}^2\Big) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have to use this oversetting often :/

Comment: @rook1996 Then you'll unfortunately have to wait for another solution, because I do not think that this is usable for many repetitions, especially if you have more than 9 of those oversets.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that sets up a dedicated macro called `\defeq`; it takes one argument, the number of the definition being invoked. The solution also sets up a macro to denote L2-norms.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert} % L_2 norm

\newcommand\defeq[1]{\overset{\mathclap{%
   \scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{Def.}\mkern1.5mu#1}}{=}\:}

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y    

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
0 &=  \partial \bigl(\tfrac{1}{2N} \norm{\y- \X\beta}_{2}^2\bigr) \\
  &\defeq{1} \nabla \bigl(\tfrac{1}{2N} \norm{\y- \X\beta}_{2}^2\bigr) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I trust you can figure out how to adapt the `\defeq` macro for other applications. E.g., create a macro called `\remeq` in which you'd replace "Def." with "Rem." ("remark").

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `\clap` command defined by `mathtools` for the overset content, and will have to add a small space afterwards, or use an `\eqmathbox` command, based on `\eqmakebox` from package `eqparbox` and enclose each of the alignment symbols within such a box. I tok the opportunity to replace your pairs of double bars with an easily scalable `\norm` command , which makes the code clearer, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][eq]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle #2$}}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
0 &=\:\partial \Big(\frac{1}{2N} \norm{\y- \X\beta}_{2}^2\Big) \\
&\overset{\mathclap{\mathrm{Def. 1}}}{=}\: \nabla \Big(\frac{1}{2N} \norm{\y- \X\beta}_{2}^2\Big)
\end{align*}


\begin{align*}
0 &\mathrel{\eqmathbox{=}}\partial \Big(\frac{1}{2N} \norm{\y- \X\beta}_{2}^2\Big) \\
&\mathrel{\eqmathbox{\overset{\mathrm{Def.1}}{=}}} \nabla \Big(\frac{1}{2N}\norm{\y- \X\beta}_{2}^2\Big)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the `aligned-overset` package you can do this by writing the `&` between the overset and the `=`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}


\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\X}{\matr{X}} %Matrix von X
\newcommand{\y}{\matr{y}} %y     

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
0 &=\partial \Big(\frac{1}{2N} ||\y- \X\beta||_{2}^2\Big) \\
\overset{\mathrm{Def. 1}}&{=} \nabla \Big(\frac{1}{2N} ||\y- \X\beta||_{2}^2\Big) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]